# How do I manually insert an item in a VB.net Combobox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I've created a `Combobox` and the list selections are being populated by a `DataTable`. I can populate it with no problems, but I need to add a default item for the list before the results from the DataTable appears.

The list should contain:

```
All Rooms and Facilities
Class Room
Laboratory
PE Facility
THE Facility
Drawing Room
Library
```

But I'm always getting:

[image]

I've been using this link as my resources:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551.aspx

And here's my code:

```
cboByRoomType.Items.Insert(0, "All Rooms and Facilities")
With cboByRoomType
    .DataSource = tempDTRoomType
    .DisplayMember = "Description"
    .ValueMember = "Room Type ID"
    .SelectedIndex = 0
End With
```

Also, I already tried to add the default item using the Items in the `Properties Window`, still no good.

Comment: Binding a new source (.DataSource = foo) clears any previously initialized items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your first row with this (which probably has a more compact form):

```
    tempDTRoomType.Rows.InsertAt(tempDTRoomType.NewRow(), 0)
    tempDTRoomType.Rows(0).Item("Description") = "All Rooms and Facilities"
    tempDTRoomType.Rows(0).Item("Room Type ID") = 0
```

Comment: Great! The point is, you want to add the entry to the underlying datasource, before you bind to the control, rather than trying to alter a databound control.